# Read a file from COS on fly using aws-sdk go

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I have a file in S3 that is being continuously modified. I will have to read it and display it live on the `stdout`.

That is, I read the first line, and if the file is modified and a second line is added, I will have to reflect those changes in my `stdout`. I want all of this to happen in a single command and without running the command multiple times to read the updated file.

I need a golang functionality like bash command "tail -f `<FILENAME>`" that reads a S3 file from COS.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to read a file on fly that is being updated over time from COS and display it on stdout

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You could potentially poll the data and compare, if it's not the same (probably should do some sort of checksum) then you would just output it.

Answer (score 1):

The design you are proposing will not work correctly

This is because

> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES
>   in all regions.

(see [Introduction to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html))

What this means in practice is that overwriting or updating an S3 object does not quickly allow reads of the same object - which is what you need to "tail" a file

I suggest you rethink the way you are monitoring the file

You haven't said why you wish to tail the file but (for example) if you are simply looking for activity then Cloudwatch can be used to get various rate metrics from S3

If your originating file is on an EC2 instance then [Cloudwatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) might be a good fit

Comment: The scenario is like this. The user would create a resource using my service. As soon as resource creation is started a log file is created in S3 as a txt file. I would like to provide the user the functionality to monitor the logs during the course of creation. For this purpose I would like to stream the logs from log file created in S3 and update the logs to user's stdout in real time.

Comment: s3 isn't suitable for what you want to do.  There are plenty of AWS queuing, streaming or logging products to choose from.  For example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html